# No such module PlaygroundSupport

Tags: ios, swift, macos, virtualbox, swift-playground

Yes weird situation.
I am using Mac OS X 10.9 Mavericks **on VirtualBox,** and a Xcode 6.1

I am currently trying to do an interactive Swift Playground for WWDC scholarship(to practice), but weirdly, when I import PlaygroundSupport, it says no such module. Does this situation ever happen before?

I have checked spelling error, but a simple

```
import PlaygroundSupport
```

returns me no such module.
Any anyone help?

Comment: That is a quite old Xcode version. I *think* it was `import XCPlayground` at that time, but you may be better off by updating to a newer version of macOS and Xcode.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Swift `PlaygroundSupport` **SDK** need minimum macOS version **10.12+** and **Xcode 8.0+**

You can see this:

1. https://developer.apple.com/documentation/playgroundsupport
2. https://developer.apple.com/documentation/playgroundsupport/playgroundpage